# Error on attempt to recieve JSON data from Cassandra DB via Java + sparkSession

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

I'm trying to read data from Cassandra table via Java + sparkSession, method should return it as a JSON.

Here is my DB:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id               uuid,
  email                  text, 
  first_name          text,
  last_name          text,
  user_password   text,
  created_date      timestamp, 
  updated_date     timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) WITH comment = 'List of all registered and active users';
```

and here is a code which should return JSON:

```
public String getAccountData(UUID userid) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        SparkSession sparkSession = config.getSparkSession();
        //"SELECT user.first_name,user.last_name, user.email FROM chat.user where user.id="+userid+";");

        Account account = new Account();
        Encoder<Account> accountEncoder = Encoders.bean(Account.class);

return sparkSession
        .read()
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
            {
                put("keyspace", "chat");
                put("table", "user");
            }
        })
        .load()
        .select("first_name", "last_name", "email")
        .filter("user_id = '" + userid +"'")
        .toJSON()
        .as(accountEncoder)
        .toString();
    }
```

and here is my Account.java file:

```
package rest.account;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Account implements Serializable {

   private String user_id;
   private String first_name;
   private String last_name;   
   private String email;

   public Account(){}

   public Account(String user_id, String first_name, String last_name, String email){
      this.user_id = user_id;
      this.first_name = first_name;
      this.last_name = last_name;
      this.email = email;
   }
   //------------------------------
   public String getId() {
      return user_id;
   }

   public void setId(String user_id) {
      this.user_id = user_id;
   }

   //------------------------------
   public String getFirstName() {
      return first_name;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String first_name) {
      this.first_name = first_name;
   }

   //------------------------------
   public String getLastName() {
          return last_name;
       }

   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
   this.last_name = last_name;
   }
   //------------------------------    
   public String getEmail() {
      return email;
   }

   public void setEmail(String email) {
      this.email = email;
   }        
}
```

And here is the output error:

> HTTP Status 500 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`email`' given
>   input columns: [value];
>
> type Exception report
>
> message org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`email`' given
>   input columns: [value];
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`email`' given
>   input columns: [value];
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:410)
>     org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169)
>   root cause
>
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`email`' given
>   input columns: [value];
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:278)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:260)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:509)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:410)
>     org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169)
>   root cause
>
> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`email`' given
>   input columns: [value];
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:77)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:74)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:301)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:301)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:300)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:321)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:179)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:319)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:298)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(TreeNode.scala:338)
>     scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$iterator$3.apply(MapLike.scala:246)
>     scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$iterator$3.apply(MapLike.scala:246)
>     scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
>     scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
>     scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
>     scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>     scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.foreach(IterableLike.scala:311)
>     scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
>     scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:25)
>     scala.collection.TraversableViewLike$class.force(TraversableViewLike.scala:88)
>     scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.force(IterableLike.scala:311)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:346)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:179)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:319)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:298)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:190)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:200)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(QueryPlan.scala:209)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:179)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:209)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:74)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:67)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:126)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:67)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:58)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.resolveAndBind(ExpressionEncoder.scala:245)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.(Dataset.scala:210)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.(Dataset.scala:167)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:59)
>     org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.as(Dataset.scala:359)
>     rest.account.AccountManager.getAccountData(AccountManager.java:58)
>     rest.account.AccountService.getAccountData(AccountService.java:28)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:410)
>     org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:169)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/9.0.0.M13 logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M13

If I have not this converter to JSON code then method returns, for example:

> [first_name: string, last_name: string, email: string]

But not a real values like First Name, Last Name, email@email.email

I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `getAccountData` method try below code.

```
return sparkSession
    .read()
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
        {
            put("keyspace", "chat");
            put("table", "user");
        }
    })
    .load()
    .select("first_name", "last_name", "email")
    .filter("user_id = '" + userid +"'")
    .toJSON()
    .first();
}
```

Comment: Hello @abaghel, thank you for the answer. That was my first attempt, I had next response: [value: string] . May be I researched in a wrong direction...

Comment: What is your expected output in String format? Or do you want to return Account object from getAccountData method?

Comment: the perfect result is: [{"first_name":"nn","last_name":"nn","email":"nn@nn.nn"}]

Comment: For multiple rows (not for this method, but this is my next step): [{"first_name":"nn","last_name":"nn","email":"nn@nn.nn"},{"first_name":"bb","last_name":"bb","email":"bb@bb.bb"}]

Comment: Then you can use "toJSON().collectAsList()" which will return you List<String> in desired format.

Comment: `.load()
       .select("first_name", "last_name", "email")
       .filter("user_id = '" + userid +"'")
       .toJSON()
       .collectAsList()
       .toString();` returns same [value: string] result to me...

Comment: Your user_id is unique UUID so it will return single value as you are filtering using user_id. Check your Database. I tested your code and it works fine. I am getting response like [{"first_name":"aaaa","last_name":"bbbb","email":"cc@gmail.com"}].

Comment: ok, thanks, will try. I'll close this one question as resolved, cause I have no error any more.